# Oracle DB update using terminal doesn't work

Tags: database, oracle, set

Im trying to update date on my oracle DB but when I do it using my terminal it doesn't work this is the code that I use :

```
UPDATE INVESTIGATOR SET CODE = 'LMA' WHERE NUMCHARACTER=8;
```

But when I do it using my Oracle SQL Developers via the interface it works and this is the code generated :

```
UPDATE "MADJID"."INVESTIGATOR" SET CODE = 'LIA' 
WHERE ROWID = 'AAATjEAAQAAAAFUAAH' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '3120887'
```

I don't understand what is ROWID and ORA_ROWSCN ? and why the first code doesn't work ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are connecting to the same service/database in both cases? (just because the connection names are the same, doesn't necessarily mean that the connection definitions are the same).  And are you connecting with the same login and rights in both cases?  It's possible that your terminal connection doesn't have read permissions on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Doesn't work" isn't exactly an error message. What does it mean? Did Oracle report any error? If so, which one?

Because, as far as we know, `UPDATE` failed because there are no rows in `investigator` table whose `numcharacter` column is equal to `8`.

---

What generated the 2nd code you posted? How come `LMA` become `LIA`? These are two different strings, I doubt that any tool is capable of doing that.

[ORA_ROWSCN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm)

> For each row, ORA_ROWSCN returns the conservative upper bound system change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row.

[ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)

> For each row in the database, the ROWID pseudocolumn returns the address of the row

---

**[EDIT: error screenshot]**

There's something strange in what you posted. SQL*Plus points (with an asterisk) to "place" which caused the error. In your case, it says that *table or view doesn't exist*, but points to a **wrong** place - to a column to be updated, while it should point to that "invalid" (non-existent) table name, like it does on my screenshot. See the comparison on the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: To add on to this, `ORA_ROWSCN` as a filter for an update would usually be to prevent lost updates - you're making sure no one has updated the row since you queried it. This is known as the optimistic locking strategy.

Comment: What I was trying to do is to change the data of a column called CODE which contain a varchar(10) of a table called INVESTIGATOR where the primary key is NUMCHARACTER but when I do it via the Terminal I get this message using the code above :

table or view does not exist

Even if it exist here are a picture :

https://i.ibb.co/4NgyqK8/Screen-Shot-2021-12-25-at-02-14-43.png

Comment: That's strange; see additional info I posted in edited answer.